# Undo Microsoft Outlook Quick Steps

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, undo

If you use Quick Steps in Microsoft Outlook, it does not appear to be undo-able.  I am currently using MS Outlook 2016, but I've found this to be the case with every version of Outlook prior.  My question is if there's a pattern, and a way around the problem?

I've already tried figuring it out but gave up.  Long ago I tested a few scenarios, but had no luck:

- is it just the actions I have it taking (mark unread and move to
  folder),
- the way companies have set up my account,  or
- perhaps the way I'm trying to undo the actions (ctrl+z)

Comment: If there isn't a way around it, what's the best way to get MS to fix it?

Comment: You may add votes in this thread in Outlook UserVoice thread:https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/322590-outlook-2016-for-windows/suggestions/34977997-undo-a-quick-steps-operation

Comment: Sadly, UserVoice is no longer available. However, you can "follow" this (very old) Feature Request thread: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/feature-request-undo-a-quick-step-operation/62e32220-d508-4559-9cb7-9a16a53179c4

Comment: Thanks @kmote I edited the accepted answer to point that out, and say to use the Windows Feedback Hub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that Outlook's action history doesn't record Quick Steps hence Ctrl+Z doesn't work (if you try moving/deleting the same e-mail manually then Ctrl+Z will work), so this is not related to your Exchange account or your method.

As for your second question, you can give feedback, but I doubt they will act on it because there has been a lot of noise around it for a long long time.

You can send feedback to Microsoft using the [Feedback Hub](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-the-feedback-hub-app-f59187f8-8739-22d6-ba93-f66612949332) app in Windows 10/11.  Access the Feedback Hub using one of the following options:

1. <kbd>[image: Windows Key] WIN</kbd> +<kbd>F</kbd>
2. Type `feedback-hub:` in one of:

   - Web browser
   - Windows "Run"  /  <kbd>[image: Windows Key] WIN</kbd> +<kbd>R</kbd>

Comment: When I mentioned my account, I meant local folder versus archive, etc.  
Tell me more about the action history.

Comment: Well, if you try moving e-mails to a folder one by one manually, by dragging them in the folder or clicking on move, that action is stored in the activity history and the Ctrl+Z option will work and also the undo option(the curved arrow pointing left on the top left corner will work), however for some reason after a quick step, that arrow stays grayed out like nothing happened. I have no idea why Microsoft isn't treating this as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread and still no new fixes in the works, sadly. However, user Michael Satta provided this suggestion in the [Answers.Microsoft forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/feature-request-undo-a-quick-step-operation/62e32220-d508-4559-9cb7-9a16a53179c4) (for use if your Quick Action happens to be a Move or Copy):

> Add the "Modified Date" column to any folders you have that you use
> your quick steps to move emails to.
>
> Sorting by the modified date in a folder you just accidentally moved a
> message to allows you to see it at the very top, regardless of the
> message's send/received date.